# Fill number for duplicate data in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to fill number for duplicate data in dataGridView. If duplicate i will fill from 1.1 to 1.(count duplicate) else don't duplicate i fill 1.1. But i use code as below it's work faile.

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView3.RowCount - 2; i++)
{
        string abc = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        for (int j = 1; j <= dataGridView3.RowCount - 2;j++ )
        {
            string def = dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "" + dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "1.1";
            if (abc == def)
            {
                count = count + 1;
                dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells["Wbs"].Value = "1." + "" + (count);

            }
        }
}
```

I hope everyone will check help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.  You are not re-setting count within your i loop, and (if I understand you correctly), you only need to check previous values in your DataGridView (ie where j < i).

So your code should look something like this:

```
int count;
dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "1.1";
for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridView3.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    count = 1;
    string abc = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "" + dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        string def = dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "" +  dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        if (abc == def)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Wbs"].Value = "1." + count.ToString();
}
```

This will work regardless of the data order.  If the data is ordered on CSIS and BSS, then you can use:

```
int count = 1;

dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "1.1";

for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridView3.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == dataGridView3.Rows[i - 1].Cells[2].Value 
&& dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == dataGridView3.Rows[i - 1].Cells[3].Value)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 1;
    }
    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells["Wbs"].Value = "1." + count.ToString();
}
```

In this case, because we are only comparing one line with its predecessor it is more efficient not to store the variables in a new variable, but to compare them directly.  Storing into a separate variable only has a speed gain, when you are saving the compiled code the trouble of de-referencing the same value multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Janathan but you can incorect understant of my mean. In datagridview, it can has duplicate data. Example: row[1] duplicate row[2] and row[6] duplicate row[10], row[12].....i don't only compare between first row and second row.

Comment: Then use the my first example.  That is why I gave both, because it was not clear.  When I say "previous values", I mean all values before the current line. Or do you mean that every duplicate line should have the same count?

Comment: Yah, I understood, but when i use code same as above. It work don't correct, only first and second row display value.

Comment: What is the dataGridView3.RowCount value?  Also step through in the debugger and see if any error is thrown.

Comment: My bad.  Sorry just seen mistake.  Please set dataGridView1 to 3 in penultimate row!  I was checking using my own code and did not change all references correctly.  I will amend code.

Comment: One other point.  If you allow user to add rows then you need i <= dataGridView3.RowCount - 2.

Comment: Yah, thank you@@ It work@@i edited for loop and it work.

Comment: Great.  Glad to have been able to fix it for you.

Comment: But i have a new problem. I want to add new row with condition. If row[i].value ="1.1" then i add row  positon below row[i] and fill value for 3 cells(wbs, CSIS, BSS) and orther cell in row is blank.

Comment: Please ask a new question, showing exactly what you want.  The best thing to do, is to show the contents of the grid now, and the contents as you would like them to be.

Comment: Yah, i created new question. I hope you will help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707952/add-row-and-fill-value-in-datagridview-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan@@

Answer (score 0):

If the list is ordered for CSIS and BSS you just need to check the row before with the actual row to determine the Wbs.

The trick here is to group before labelling and then just check the one before with the one after.

I think you can reason better if you use poco object before handling them at datagrid view, here some not tested code, **but you can use more or less the same code on Rows and Cells**.

```
class Data {
  String Wbs { get; set; }
  String Csis { get; set; }
  String Bss { get; set; }
  String CsisAndBss() => Csis + Bss;
}

var list = new Data { ... }; // objects

list.OrderBy( ... ); // Csis then Bss

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; list++){
  var actual = list[i];
  var before = list[i-1]; // check list boundaries
  if(i==0 || before.CsisAndBss != actual.CsisAndBss){
    actual.Wbs == "1.1";
    continue;
  }
  var values = before.Wbs.Split(".");
  actual.Wbs = $"{values[0]}.{Int32.Parse(values[1]+1)}";
}

// here pass data to the grid
```

Comment: Thanks Giulio , but your mean is use List<>? I don't understant clearly.

Comment: I read data from excel so i compare data direct in datagridview. I think it not optimize but i don't know other way.

Comment: I'll add the datagrid version.

Comment: :) :) Not late baby :v :v I have a new problem :v If you free can you help me :v :v :v https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707952/add-row-and-fill-value-in-datagridview-c-sharp

Comment: @KateMid I suggest you to load your data inside poco objects using something like dapper and then use those objects. Everything will be easier...