# Add row and fill value in dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem. I want to add new row with condition if row[i].value ="1.1" then i add row has positon above row[i] and fill value for 3 cells(other cells is blank).Before [![enter image description here][1]][1]  After [![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Your question _”I have a problem. I want to add new row with condition if row[i].value ="1.1" then i add row has positon above row[i] and fill value for 3 cells(other cells is blank).Before”_...makes no sense. You may want to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that shows how SO works. In addition, you may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also if you need [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help).(http://stackoverflow.com/help). Please make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having first loaded your DataGridView you then need to pass the DataTable that was the initial source through to a method that looks similar to this:

```
private void addExtraRows(DataTable dT)
{

    DataTable newTable = dT.Clone();
    DataRow nR;
    int lastRow = dT.Rows.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastRow; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "1.1")
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < dT.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dT.Rows[j][2] == dT.Rows[i][2] && dT.Rows[j][3] == dT.Rows[i][3])
                {
                    nR = newTable.NewRow();
                    nR[0] = dT.Rows[i][0];
                    nR[1] = "1";
                    nR[2] = dT.Rows[i][2];
                    nR[3] = dT.Rows[i][3];
                    newTable.Rows.Add(nR);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        nR = newTable.NewRow();
        nR[0] = dT.Rows[i][0];
        nR[1] = dT.Rows[i][1];
        nR[2] = dT.Rows[i][2];
        nR[3] = dT.Rows[i][3];
        nR[4] = dT.Rows[i][4];
        newTable.Rows.Add(nR);
    }
    nR = newTable.NewRow();
    nR[0] = dT.Rows[lastRow][0];
    nR[1] = dT.Rows[lastRow][1];
    nR[2] = dT.Rows[lastRow][2];
    nR[3] = dT.Rows[lastRow][3];
    nR[4] = dT.Rows[lastRow][4];
    newTable.Rows.Add(nR);

    dataGridView3.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView3.DataSource = newTable;
    return;
}
```

Please note that you may need to change the name of the dataGridView!

Edit:

Assuming that the DataSource of your DataGridView is a DataTable then you can change the start of the method to:

```
private void addExtraRows()
{
    DataTable dT = (DataTable)dataGridView3.DataSource;
    DataTable newTable = dT.Clone();
```

Now all you have to do is to call this routine after your grid has loaded.

Comment: Yah, Jonathan dT is datatable has data from recieve dataGridView?I don't understood clearly this point.

Comment: You need to pass the DataTable used to first load the DataGridView to this method as a parameter.

Comment: Your mean :  Datatable dT = new Datatable ; dT=(Datatable)dataGridview1.datasource; Sorry but i'm newbie, i study so bad :(

Comment: Thanks Jonathan@@It good work and i edited a little because i use bindingsource@@Again, thanks so much Jonathan, you helped me very much@@

Comment: My pleasure.  Have a great evening!